# Basic authentication in Luigi with nginx does not work, if I write a port in the address, what should I do?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, luigi

Good day! I am trying to set up basic authentication in Luigi. I decided to do it through nginx, wrote the simplest code in the configs `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`:

```
location / {
    auth_basic "Log in procedure";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.luigipasswd;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
}
```

Works great. If I go to my address 162.237.118.4 (for example), then a window pops up in my browser to enter a login and password.

But if I enter the address together with the port 162.237.118.4:8082, then the entire UI opens without a password (

Can anyone suggest where to dig? The second day I was in thought.

Answer (score 1):

If you enter the address together with the port `162.237.118.4:8082` into your browser, then you are bypassing the basic auth config in Nginx, and therefore you wouldn't be asked to enter it.

You should think about denying remote connections to the service running on `8082` so that it can only be accessed via Nginx.